# Sequelize-auto for Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've read that [Sequelize-Auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) is a real solution for mirroring a DB schema that contains tables already. But I've not found any documentation for do it.

Any clue or suggestion in order to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the link you just provide you have [Usage](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto#usage) and an [Example](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto#example).